# Implement string search field for a Date

Tags: java, spring, date

I am trying to implement a String search field that will search for a Date. Whole date will be like

```
2020-10-10
```

I am parsing this String to a date and searching in the database for entries on this date. I can create a helper class and check if the input String is a valid date like this

```
public class DateValidatorUsingDateFormat implements DateValidator {
    private String dateFormat;

    public DateValidatorUsingDateFormat(String dateFormat) {
        this.dateFormat = dateFormat;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String dateStr) {
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(this.dateFormat);
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        try {
            sdf.parse(dateStr);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

What if I want to input

```
2020
```

and search for all entries from 2020 year ? Or maybe

```
2019-10
```

and search for all entries from Octomber 2019 ?

Comment: Use `like` phrase from SQL `SELECT * from employee WHERE dob like '1997-04%';` it will work fine with date for year `SELECT * from employee WHERE dob like '1997-%';` You can also try diff combinations for month and day

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).